# What happens to reviews when app is closed for sale in a country in app store?

Tags: app-store

I need to close my application for my country for a while. But I'm curious about what is going to happen to all of my reviews for my application? Are those will be deleted when I again open back for sale?

Best regards, 
Kemal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you from experience that when you remove an app from sale in any country the data behind your app is still there.  When you make your app public again all of your old comments and reviews are still there.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this.

But my best guess is that the reviews persist based on the app version number and not when its made un/available for a country.

So if the version number remains the same, nothing should happen to the reviews.

Thinking of it, if reviews got deleted on making it unavailable from a country, all apps with bad reviews would do this, and start with fresh reviews.